# Why am I not able to search short words in my Laravel Application?

Tags: mysql, laravel, full-text-search

This is my search function. With it I am able to search whole words and numbers perfectly. However, I am not able to search short words like 'the'.

```
public function search($search)
 {
        $goodString = $this->makeString($search);
        $search_results = Model::select('*')->selectRaw('MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance', [$goodString])->whereRaw('MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$goodString])->orderBy('relevance', 'desc');

        return $search_results;
 }
```

I am using:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

`Ubuntu 16.04`

I made changes to the mysql config `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set the following:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
ft_min_word_len = 2
```

After that I restarted the mysql servel and went on to rebuild my Fulltext tables with the following commands in mysql:

```
set GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=ON;
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;
```

Then I restarted the mysql server again and nothing. No results when I search "the", "of", "at" etc.

So my question is, what should I do in order to be able to search short words and numeric values like '10' or '20' etc?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

This is how I created the fulltext search via Laravel:

On migrating I added the following at the end of the `Schema::create` function

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE news ADD FULLTEXT search(title)');`

Also, if there is double number in the title like "13" I can't get a results when  I search for 13.

A follow up question:

Is it possible to search for partial match word in FULLTEXT search? At the moment I break the words of the string and make string such as "+search +string +here" is it possible to find a match if a word "searched" exists in the titles?

Comment: Full text search index is also on the column?

Comment: do you have those words separately in your database? Or they belong to a sentences.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I edited my question and showed how I made the fulltext with laravel.

Comment: @JuliusFasema they exist in titles, I am able to search longer words bot not shorter ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words you mention are known as stop words (soo frequent that are ignored)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes

You can create a new (shorter) list and use that.Make sure you change the documentation to your Mysql version.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way I can remove this ignore? However, I just checked, when I search for "47" I know in my DB that I have several news with this number in the title, but none results were shown.

Answer (score 0):

to effect a search of words in your sentences, use this:

```
preg_match("/{$wordsOrSentenceFromDB}/i", $WordsYouEnteredFromForm);
```

Comment: Will this help me sort my results by relevance on most matches by different words?

Comment: Can you help me out for the implementation of `preg_match` with my function. Can't figure out how to do it so far.

Comment: I will definitely going to need some asistance with the `preg_match` I cant even start to us it with my current function.